# Magento extend community module into local module

Tags: magento, model, module, controller, extend

We are trying to call an action from a community module's model in our local controller. We've never done something like this before and we are having trouble getting it to work.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain exactly what needs to be done step by step!

Below is the code for the action in the local controller calling the action saveData in the community module's model.

```
public function onsubmitAction()
{
   foreach ($_POST['ch'] as $entity_id) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($entity_id);
    $haschildren = false; 
    if (count($category->getChildren())) {
        $haschildren = true; 
    }
    saveData($category, $haschildren);
    }
}
```

Comment: try as like controller overrideing

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR can you explain further? or provide a link? We found a guide for overriding the core but we need one for overriding local files

Comment: Provide community module controller name

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understand you, you need to call `saveData` method from community module MODEL? What's the problem: `Mage::getModel('communitymodule/modelname')->saveData($args)` doesn't work?

Comment: @waldek_c We tried calling Mage::getModel('countdown/category')->saveData($args) but that did not work. The file structure is comprised of a folder called Belvg\Countdown\Model\Observer\ and inside Observer there are 3 files: Category.php, Product.php, and ChangeStatus.php; the action we need saveData is in Category.php

Comment: ok, I'm not 100% sure but try `Mage::getModel('countdown/observer_category')->saveData(...)`